# How to test component functionality in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Hi I am new to unit testing, I have a component that render with a list of products and display those. I also have a function in that component that filter those products by price range. I used ReactSlider which basically update two state variable 'priceFrom' and 'priceTo' and when those state varible change, I triggered a function which filter's the products according to those price. So I want to test the similiar functionality in jest. Is it possible in jest? if so, how could I achieve that, and if not which alternative approach can i take to accomplish the unit testing for this component. Thanks. The code for the component is below. Please note that in the code below when **ReactSlider** update any values, the **filterItem** function filter the products and update the ui.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from './productsList.module.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSpinner } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import Backdrop from "../../Others/Backdrop/backdrop";
import Modal from '../../Others/Modal/modal';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import ReactSlider from 'react-slider';
import { disableScroll } from "../../Others/HelperFunction/helperFunction";
import { ContextProvider } from "../../Others/AuthContext/authContext";
import './slider.css';

const ProductsList = () => {

    const context = useContext(ContextProvider);

    const productId = useParams().productId;

    const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

    const [backdrop, setBackdrop] = useState(false);

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    const [status, setStatus] = useState('');

    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

    const [priceFrom, setPriceFrom] = useState(0);

    const [priceTo, setPriceTo] = useState(10000);

    const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);

    const [itemNotFound, setItemNotFound] = useState(false);

    const itemPerPage = 9;

    const endOffset = itemOffset + itemPerPage;

    let pageCount = 0;

    if (filteredProducts.length){
        pageCount = Math.ceil(filteredProducts.length / itemPerPage);
    }

    else {
        pageCount = Math.ceil(products.length / itemPerPage);
    }

    const handlePageClick = (event) => {
        if (filteredProducts.length){
            const newOffset = (event.selected * itemPerPage) % filteredProducts.length;
            setItemOffset(newOffset);
        }
        else {
            const newOffset = (event.selected * itemPerPage) % products.length;
            setItemOffset(newOffset);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        if (context.data !== undefined){
            const product = context.data[productId] !== undefined ? context.data[productId] : [];
            if (product.length){
                setProducts(product);
                setStatus('success');
            }
            else {
                setStatus('not found');
            }
        }
    }, [context.data] );

    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, [itemOffset, filteredProducts.length]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (backdrop){
            disableScroll();
        }
        else {
            window.onscroll = () => {
                
            }
        }
    }, [backdrop])

    let defaultView = Array.from(Array(12).keys()).map(item => {
            return <div key={item} className={styles.defaultItemContainer} id={styles.loader}>
            <div className={styles.defaultItemImgContainer}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSpinner} spinPulse className={styles.spinnerPulse} />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.loadingName}></div>
            <div className={styles.loadingLink}></div>
        </div>
    });

    if (products.length){
        if (!itemNotFound && filteredProducts.length){
            defaultView = filteredProducts.slice(itemOffset, endOffset).map(item => {
            return <div key={item._id} className={styles.productsContainer} id={styles.loader}>
                    <a href={`/products/${productId}/${item.name}`} className={styles.productsLink}>
                        <div className={styles.productsImgContainer}>
                            <img src={item.img[0]} alt={item.name} className={styles.productsImg}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.productsName}>{item.name}</div>
                        <div className={styles.productsPrice}>&#2547;{item.price}</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            });
        }
        else if (itemNotFound) {
            defaultView = <div className={styles.notFoundContainer}>
                <h2 className={styles.notFoundHeader}>Nothing found based on your range</h2>
            </div>
        }

        else {
            defaultView = products.slice(itemOffset, endOffset).map(item => {
            return <div key={item._id} className={styles.productsContainer} id={styles.loader}>
                    <a href={`/products/${productId}/${item.name}`} className={styles.productsLink}>
                        <div className={styles.productsImgContainer}>
                            <img src={item.img[0]} alt={item.name} className={styles.productsImg}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.productsName}>{item.name}</div>
                        <div className={styles.productsPrice}>&#2547;{item.price}</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            });
        }
    }
    else if(status === 'not found') {
        defaultView = <div className={styles.fallbackContainer}>
            <h2 className={styles.fallbackHeader}>Nothing found</h2>
        </div>
    }

    const filterItem = () => {
        if (priceFrom && priceTo) {
            const filteredData = products.filter(item => Number(item.price) >= priceFrom && Number(item.price) <= priceTo);
            if (filteredData.length){
                setItemNotFound(false)
                setFilteredProducts(filteredData);
                setSidebar(false);
                setBackdrop(false);
            }
            else {
                setItemNotFound(true);
                setItemOffset(0);
                setSidebar(false);
                setBackdrop(false);
            }
        }
    }

    const resetFilter = () => {
        setPriceFrom(0);
        setPriceTo(1000);
        setFilteredProducts([]);
    }

    const openSidebar = () => {
        if (!sidebar){
            setSidebar(true);
            setBackdrop(true);
        }
    }

    const closeSidebar = () => {
        if (sidebar){
            setSidebar(false);
            setBackdrop(false);
        }
        else {
            setBackdrop(false);
        }
    }

    let displayStatus = <div className={styles.statusMsgContainer}>
        <h2 className={styles.statusMsgHeader}>Something went wrong</h2>
        <p className={styles.statusMsgP}>Please try again</p>
        <button className={styles.statusMsgBtn} onClick={() => {
            setModal(false);
        }}>Ok</button>
    </div>

    if (status === 'database error'){
        displayStatus = <div className={styles.statusMsgContainer}>
            <h2 className={styles.statusMsgHeader}>Database error</h2>
            <p className={styles.statusMsgP}>Please try again or contact the admin</p>
            <button className={styles.statusMsgBtn} onClick={() => {
            setError(false);
            setStatus('');
            setModal(false);
        }}>Ok</button>
        </div>
    }

    return (
        <>
        <Backdrop backdrop={ backdrop } toggleBackdrop={ closeSidebar }/>
        <Modal modal={modal}>
            {displayStatus}
        </Modal>
        <div className={styles.productsListMain}>
            <div className={styles.productsListContainer}>
                <div className={styles.sidebarSwitcher} onClick={ openSidebar }>
                    <p className={styles.sidebarSwitcherP}>Show Sidebar</p>
                </div>
                <div className={ sidebar ? `${styles.sidebarContainer} ${styles.on}` : styles.sidebarContainer}>
                    <div className={styles.categoryType}>
                        <h2 className={styles.categoryH2}>Categories</h2>
                        <ul className={styles.sidebarLists}>
                            <a href="/products/Bracelet" className={styles.sidebarLink}><li className={productId === 'Bracelet' ? `${styles.sidebarList} ${styles.active}` : styles.sidebarList}>Bracelets</li></a>
                            <a href="/products/Finger Ring" className={styles.sidebarLink}><li className={productId === 'Finger Ring' ? `${styles.sidebarList} ${styles.active}` : styles.sidebarList}>Finger Rings</li></a>
                            <a href="/products/Ear Ring" className={styles.sidebarLink}><li className={productId === 'Ear Ring' ? `${styles.sidebarList} ${styles.active}` : styles.sidebarList}>Ear Rings</li></a>
                            <a href="/products/Necklace" className={styles.sidebarLink}><li className={productId === 'Necklace' ? `${styles.sidebarList} ${styles.active}` : styles.sidebarList}>Necklace</li></a>
                            <a href="/products/Toe Ring" className={styles.sidebarLink}><li className={productId === 'Toe Ring' ? `${styles.sidebarList} ${styles.active}` : styles.sidebarList}>Toe Ring</li></a>
                            <a href="/products/Other" className={styles.sidebarLink}><li className={productId === 'Other' ? `${styles.sidebarList} ${styles.active}` : styles.sidebarList}>Others</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div className={styles.categoryType} id={styles.categoryType2}>
                        <h2 className={styles.categoryH2}>Price Range</h2>
                        <ReactSlider
                            max={10000}
                            className="horizontal-slider"
                            thumbClassName="example-thumb"
                            trackClassName="example-track"
                            value={[priceFrom, priceTo]}
                            ariaLabel={['Lower thumb', 'Upper thumb']}
                            ariaValuetext={state => `Thumb value ${state.valueNow}`}
                            renderThumb={(props, state) => <div {...props}>{state.valueNow}</div>}
                            minDistance={1}
                            onChange={([v1, v2]) => {
                                setPriceFrom(v1);
                                setPriceTo(v2);
                            }}
                            pearling
                        />
                        <button disabled={!priceFrom || !priceTo}
                                className={styles.filterBtn}
                                onClick={ resetFilter }>Reset</button>
                        <button disabled={(!priceFrom || !priceTo) || (priceFrom >= priceTo)}
                                className={styles.filterBtn}
                                onClick={filterItem}>Apply</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className={styles.ProductsLists}>
                    <h2 className={styles.productHeader}>{products.length ? products[0].category : null}</h2>
                    <div className={styles.productsDisplayContainer}>
                        {defaultView}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ReactPaginate breakLabel="..."
                           nextLabel=">"
                           className={styles.paginationContainer}
                           pageClassName={styles.paginationItem}
                           previousClassName={styles.previousItem}
                           nextClassName={styles.nextItem}
                           activeClassName={styles.paginationActive}
                           disabledClassName={styles.paginationDisabled}
                           onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                           pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                           pageCount={itemNotFound ? 0 : pageCount}
                           previousLabel="<"
                           renderOnZeroPageCount={null}/>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ProductsList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some advice that I can give you related to your questions

- Check a library that could help you testing elements in react (like react-testing-library https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/)
- Usually things that come from another library are not tested because we asume that the library itself already tested it (in that case the ReactSlider library
- Try to split your component into smaller ones so it is easier to test (you can play with props) and the dependencies inside each one will be less
- We can divide testing here in two different tests **E2E** and **unit testing**, E2E is when you use a tool that simulates user interaction in this case you can simulate an user moving range slider and see what happens after that (for this you can use cypress or selenium) these tools runs in browser like a human would do it, unit test allows you to test functions, components inputs and outputs, here you can also simulate clicks and interactions but they are not strong as E2E for user interactions because unit testing (jest in this case as a tool) runs tests in a JSDOM that is a simulation of a real browser (in simple words)

In order to tackle this I will do the following

- Install and take a look to testing library and jest
- Split your components in smaller ones
- Try to skip the ReactSlider test itself and delegate it to the library
- With unit test you can test the filter passing props to it (after separate it in another component) and check with testing library how it behaves with different props passed to it
- With Cypress or Selenium you can test more deeply what happens when you move that slider in the browser

Cypress: https://www.cypress.io/ 
Selenium: https://www.selenium.dev/

Remember that E2E and Unit Testing are two approaches that will serve you the best depending of what are you looking for each one can simulate user interactions but the engines behind that are different

Hope it helps